# Calcular la media de consumo

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla en una base de datos:

```
consumo

pk_consumo   fk_ruta    fk_vehiculo   fecha      kms     litros    litrosx100
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1           1          1      2018-04-25    345.000   80         
   2           2          2      2018-04-26    351.000   70           
   3           3          1      2018-04-27    360.000   60           x
```

Cada vehículo hace una ruta y en cada ruta puede hacer un respostaje de gasolina.

Quiero hacer una media de litros consumidos en una ruta con un `SELECT`, pero del vehiculo numero `1`. En este caso tenemos 3 rutas diferentes. Quiero hacer la media de consumo en la ruta número 3, donde está la x.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo? He intentado muchas cosas pero no consigo que salga.

La fórmula que tengo pensada es la siguiente:

```
((kms de ruta 3 - kms de ruta 1)/100) / litros de la ruta 3
```

El resultado que deseo es el siguiente:

```
pk_consumo   fk_ruta    fk_vehiculo   fecha      kms     litros    litrosx100
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1           1          1      2018-04-25    345.000   80         
   2           2          2      2018-04-26    351.000   70           
   3           3          1      2018-04-27    360.000   60          4,5
```

He intentado lo siguiente, pero no me sale bien:

```
select (((select sum(kms) from consumo where pk_consumo = 3) - (select sum(kms) from consumo where pk_consumo = (3-1)))/100)/(select sum(litros) from consumo where pk_consumo = 3) total 
from consumo 
where fk_vehiculo = 2 
group by total
```

Comment: ¿Podrías poner que es lo que has intentado hasta ahora? consumo es ¿tu única tabla? si es así, aunque la pregunta es sencilla, te recomiendo que crees un [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)  que puedes compartir para que te ayuden.

Comment: Hola @Xerox , ¿podrías agregar el esquema de tu tabla, algunos datos para reproducir el problema y uno o dos ejemplos del resultado esperado? Eso nos facilitaría el trabajo y la comprensión del problema. Se denomina [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable (MCVE)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y es la mejor herramienta que nos puedes ofrecer para ayudarte. Gracias.

Comment: Ahora mismo os pongo un ejemplo

Comment: Ahí está el resultado esperado, tengo dos tablas más que son `ruta` y `vehiculo`, cada una con su `pk` correspondiente

Comment: @Aritzbn Ahí está lo que intenté pero me daba error

Comment: @Xerox, veo que has editado tu pregunta mientras respondía, así que voy a adaptar mi respuesta a los nuevos datos que propones.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Vale sí gracias, te lo iba a comentar ahora mismo. En un `SELECT` no se podría hacer eso? Olvidándonos por ejemplo de la última columna de `litrosx100`. Imaginate que esa columna no está pero quiero saber el consumo medio de la ruta 3

Comment: Estoy editando para responder a tu pregunta. En cuanto a la nueva duda, ¿calcular el promedio de consumo de una ruta? Eso es mucho más complejo porque hay que obtener el consumo anterior de cada conductor antes de pasar por esa ruta para el cálculo.

Comment: Vale vale, espero a que edites tu respuesta. Más que nada era para que no creara otra tabla ya que el resultado que dá es otra tabla

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76581/discussion-between-xerox-and-oscargarcia).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta consulta SQL se basa en una obtención de todos los registros requeridos de la `<ruta deseada>` y uno a uno obtiene el registro inmediatamente anterior del mismo vehículo para calcular la distancia que ha recorrido en ella y el consumo que tuvo de combustible:

```
SELECT
  co.*,
  100 * (litros_a - litros) / (kms - kms_a) litrosx100
FROM (
  SELECT
   *,
   (
     SELECT kms
     FROM consumo co2
     WHERE
       co1.fk_vehiculo = co2.fk_vehiculo AND co2.pk_consumo < co1.pk_consumo
     ORDER BY pk_consumo DESC
     LIMIT 1
   ) kms_a,
   (
     SELECT litros
     FROM consumo co2
     WHERE
       co1.fk_vehiculo = co2.fk_vehiculo AND co2.pk_consumo < co1.pk_consumo
     ORDER BY pk_consumo DESC
     LIMIT 1
   ) litros_a
  FROM consumo co1
  WHERE fk_ruta = <ruta deseada>
) co
WHERE kms_a IS NOT NULL;
```

Las consultas anidadas obtienen un listado del más reciente al más viejo de los viajes del mismo vehículo, quedándonos con los datos de `litros` y `kms` del más reciente:

```
SELECT litros
  FROM consumo co2
  WHERE
    co1.fk_vehiculo = co2.fk_vehiculo AND co2.pk_consumo < co1.pk_consumo
  ORDER BY pk_consumo DESC
  LIMIT 1
```

Una vez resuelta la consulta anidada `co` descartamos aquellos viajes en los que no se pueda realizar el cálculo de consumo porque no tienen un registro anterior con:

```
WHERE kms_a IS NOT NULL
```

Y el cálculo lo he modificado al siguiente para calcular correctamente el consumo a los 100 Km:

```
100 * (litros_a - litros) / (kms - kms_a)
```

Versión en línea: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nd5cqXLgwsSFkSgYWcAGY8/13

Tras lo [debatido en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76581/discussion-between-xerox-and-oscargarcia) cambio la forma en la que soluciono el problema agregando soporte para múltiples vehículos. Para ver la respuesta anterior [pulse aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/159365/2).