# Problema contando todos los registros por especialidad y agregar registro con total

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito sacar el total de todos los registros por especialidad y, a su vez, sumar esta cantidad de registros.

Ésta es mi consulta SQL:

```
SELECT t.empresa,
       Count(t.idespecialidad) AS todos,
       e.nombre                AS nombre_especialidad
FROM   tickets AS t
       LEFT JOIN especialidad AS e
              ON t.idespecialidad = e.idespecialidad
WHERE  t.empresa = '3'
   AND t.status = '4'
   AND t.cierre_ticket BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-31'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SUM',
       Count(t.idespecialidad),
       e.nombre AS nombre_especialidad
FROM   tickets AS t
       LEFT JOIN especialidad AS e
              ON t.idespecialidad = e.idespecialidad
WHERE  t.empresa = '3'
   AND t.status = '4'
   AND t.cierre_ticket BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-31'
GROUP  BY e.nombre,
          t.empresa
```

Resultado que obtengo actualmente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Te has fijado que en la segunda consulta (la segunda parte de la unión) tiene un `SELECT 'SUM',` que es el que te provoca la salida del texto `SUM` en el campo? ¿No habrías querido decir `SELECT SUM(*)`? Si quieres que te prestemos una mejor ayuda comparte el esquema y algunos datos de ejemplo en alguna plataforma como [https://www.db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com).

Comment: Ya lo hago y te paso el link

Comment: Pero si entiendes lo que quiero haceR?

Comment: Sí, lo entiendo, pero prefiero no invertir 10-15 minutos en recrear tus tablas y datos de ejemplo para mostrarte la solución que puedo desarrollar en un db-fiddle en 5 minutos. PD: He usado un formateador en línea de SQL para mejorar la lectura de la consulta. PD2: Para capturar sólo la ventana actual y no todo el escritorio, usa `<Alt> + <Impr.Pant>`

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bpWkEQp5hTDH2pra76VZtU/1 Dime si puedes entrar a este link por favor

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bpWkEQp5hTDH2pra76VZtU/1 dime si puedes entrar a este link

Comment: ¿Pudiste entrar?

Comment: Voy, disculpa la tardanza.

Comment: Tranquilo amigo gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El trabajo puede realizarse haciendo uso de `GROUP BY` en la consulta principal (en caso contrario te saldrá el total):

```
SELECT t.empresa,
       COUNT(t.idespecialidad) AS todos,
       e.nombre                AS nombre_especialidad
FROM   tickets AS t
       LEFT JOIN especialidad AS e
              ON t.idespecialidad = e.idespecialidad
WHERE  t.empresa = '3'
   AND t.status = '4'
   AND t.cierre_ticket BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-31'
GROUP  BY e.nombre,
          t.empresa
```

En la segunda consulta un `COUNT(*)` sin un `GROUP BY` asociado para que cuente todos los registros obtenidos por el `WHERE`:

```
SELECT t.empresa,
       COUNT(*) todos,
       'Total' nombre_especialidad
FROM   tickets AS t
       LEFT JOIN especialidad AS e
              ON t.idespecialidad = e.idespecialidad
WHERE  t.empresa = '3'
   AND t.status = '4'
   AND t.cierre_ticket BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-31'
```

---

La consulta SQL completa quedaría:

```
SELECT t.empresa,
       COUNT(t.idespecialidad) AS todos,
       e.nombre                AS nombre_especialidad
FROM   tickets AS t
       LEFT JOIN especialidad AS e
              ON t.idespecialidad = e.idespecialidad
WHERE  t.empresa = '3'
   AND t.status = '4'
   AND t.cierre_ticket BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-31'
GROUP  BY e.nombre,
          t.empresa
UNION ALL
SELECT t.empresa,
       COUNT(*) todos,
       'Total' nombre_especialidad
FROM   tickets AS t
       LEFT JOIN especialidad AS e
              ON t.idespecialidad = e.idespecialidad
WHERE  t.empresa = '3'
   AND t.status = '4'
   AND t.cierre_ticket BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-31'
```

Puedes ver un [ejemplo en línea aquí](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bpWkEQp5hTDH2pra76VZtU/6).

Comment: Amigo una consulta ahi mismo en la consulta puedo hacer una operacion matematica? quiero sacar el porcentaje de las especialidades

Comment: Gracias amigo si porque necesito sacar estadistica el porcentaje de cada registro

Comment: Echa un vistazo a esta respuesta por si te es de utilidad. Hace uso de consultas anidadas para obtener los datos con los que luego se opera: [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/159348/calcular-la-media-de-consumo/159365#159365](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/159348/calcular-la-media-de-consumo/159365#159365)

Comment: Pero tu me recomendias hacer la operacion ahi mismo en la consulta? si sabes a lo que me refiero?

Comment: Ya vale amigo gracias

Comment: Amigo.. ¿Estas?

Comment: Si por favor....

Comment: @Oswuell, no te encuentro como usuario para enviarte invitación. Pásate por [https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170980/conversacion-entre-oscar-y-oswuell](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170980/conversacion-entre-oscar-y-oswuell) y serás dado de alta automáticamente al entrar al chat.

Comment: Me dice que tengo que tener 20 reputaciones para poder hablar en el chat.. Que hago ahora?

Comment: Me dice esto You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq.

Comment: Vale amigo gracias..